# How to list compiled in Bash options? (Cygwin)

Tags: bash

My Bash doesn't seem to have been compiled with the [`--enable-net-redirections` option](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/bash-cookbook/0596526784/ch15s09.html).

Now I'm wondering: Is there a way to make Bash list its enabled/disabled compile time options?

(Something like `bash --extra-verbose-version` maybe? I couldn't find anything. I tried the [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Invoking-Bash.html), Google, and even `strings bash` on an enabled and a non-enabled version.)

Comment: What distro do you use?

Comment: @YurijGoncharuk: Flavors of CygWin on Win10. I tried running [testssl.sh](https://testssl.sh/) on the BusyBox-CygWin built into [MobaXterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) and couldn't get it to work. (I guess busybox was to blame for that.) It did however work on vanilla Cygwin.

Answer (score 3):

I found this for `cygwin`:

1) You can download source for your version of `bash` (for example for [bash-4.4.11.2)](http://linux.rz.ruhr-uni-bochum.de/download/cygwin/x86_64/release/bash/bash-4.4.11-2-src.tar.xz).

2) Unpack it and open file `bash.cygport`:

```
$ tar -xJf bash-4.4.11-2-src.tar.xz
$ cd bash-4.4.11-2.src/
$ less bash.cygport
```

3) Find string that begins with `CYGCONF_ARGS=` (configure options for `cygwin` bash port):

```
CYGCONF_ARGS="
        --without-libintl-prefix --without-libiconv-prefix
        --with-installed-readline
        bash_cv_dev_stdin=present
        bash_cv_dev_fd=standard
        bash_cv_termcap_lib=libncurses
"
```

Comment: Okay. But what if you don't have the source/makefile? I was sort of assuming that there'd simply have to be a way to make Bash tell you *Hi, my name is Bash, my version is X.Y, and my compiled options are A, B and C.* or something to that effect.

Comment: I know, that looks strange. I saw most of programs which produce info about configure options and I can draw a conclusion that most count of this programs are servers (daemons). Why is it? Because servers are important components and administrator must knows all their capabilities before (in time) configuring. Yes, `bash` is important system component but developers of bash decided there are no need to know about configure options because **main** functionality of bash doesn't depend on it and it just auxiliary capabilities. **It's just my point of view.**